# libdigest-sha1-perl not found on repositories ubuntu 12.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu

Is there a way to install libdigest-sha1-perl on my ubuntu 12.04?
I found this:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/85191944/libdigest-sha1-perl_2.13-2build2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libdigest-sha1-perl_2.13-2build2_amd64.deb
```

**(change amd64 to i386, if y on 32bit)**

but when i change to i386 instead of amd64 i get a "can't find".

Is there a better way to install it? I'm on ubuntu 12.04 32bit.

I need this package 'cause compiling a source i get this error message:

Can't locate Digest/SHA1.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl

Thanks very much

Comment: Do you really need ubuntu package? Would the installation from CPAN enough for you? `cpan Digest::SHA1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu has deprecated Digest::SHA1 (which is why libdigest-sha1-perl provides). As such, you will not be able to install it as a .deb until someone builds a package for it (like the above amd64 package).

In the mean time, to compile your software, you can manually install the perl module through cpanm:

```
apt-get install cpanm
cpanm -i Digest::SHA1
```

This will install Digest::SHA1. Note that every time Ubuntu updates the Perl package, you will need to reinstall this.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.10 the package is named cpanminus and in order for those commands to work properly they have to be issued by the user root (or by using sudo accordingly).

Comment: pkg name seems to have changed to cpanminus; so `apt-get install cpanminus`

Answer (score 5):

This works for me on **WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** (**2022**):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cpanminus
cpanm -i Digest::SHA1
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 as well. apt install cpanm did not work for me.,